# How to send email with ReactJS and SendGrid?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have setup and account on SendGrid. I have got the API key and Node.js methods. I am creating an web app with React js. I want to send emails through SendGrid. I am unable to find any solution. Please help me with my question with an example.

Comment: I assume you mean SendGrid?

Comment: React is just a view library (front-end) You'd need to set up a backend (server) Here's the lib with examples for Node.js: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs

Answer (score 4):

Its not possible with react as it is a frontEnd library, if you try to implement with react you will get these errors

---> Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"

If you need to set those headers then you'll need to make the request from your server and not your visitor's browser.

So this is not possible from react and you will need to use some backend or firebase for it.

Comment: There are many libraries which claims to support sending mails from client-side. Basically, if you set no-cors, you will be able to send mail without any problem. You won't face problem which you face when you set no-cors for other REST requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MailJS](https://www.emailjs.com), and use sendgrid for transactional services.
It's easy to use.

Comment: Great recommendation!! @Anroche

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions available.

1. You could use nodeMailer : https://nodemailer.com/about/
2. Node mailer even has transport dwritten specifically for Sendgrid : https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer-sendgrid-transport
3. You could use node package by sendgrid itself : https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/tree/main/packages/mail

Answer (score 0):

```
//Form.js
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.target);

    fetch('/api/form-submit-url', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="username">Enter username</label>
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />

        <label htmlFor="email">Enter your email</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" />

        <label htmlFor="birthdate">Enter your birth date</label>
        <input id="birthdate" name="birthdate" type="text" />

        <button>Send data!</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
//index.js

    const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
    sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
    const msg = {
      to: test@example.com',
      from: 'test@example.com',
      subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
      text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
      html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
    };

sgMail.send(msg);
```

Comment: your answer good i will suggest add more informative like send form data in email

Comment: he has asked if email gets sent via ReactJS. Though you have written the code in ReactJS, but actually it runs only in nodejs and not in react. https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers