# Dealing with Promises and error handling in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am new to React and Next.js I am trying to send an email via sendGrid from a contact form. I have combined a couple of tutorials to get what I want but I am clearly not understanding something.

Using Next.js I have a contact form /pages/contact.js onSubmit calls /pages/api/sendMail which imports a function sendMailToMe() from utils/sendMailToMe.js

The code works and sends the email but I cannot seem to pass the result from sendMailToMe() back to sendMail.js

```
/utils/sendMailToMe.js
    const sendMailToMe = async (
  fullName, 
  formMessage, 
  email 
) => {

  const mail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
  mail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);
  
const msg = {
  to: 'mike@mydomain.com',
  from: 'mike@mydomain.com',
  templateId: 'd-3481ff06ea924128baa7c16a5a7f4840',
  dynamicTemplateData: {
    subject: 'Testing Templates',
    fullName: fullName,
    message: formMessage,
  },
};
mail.send(msg)
.then((response) => {
  console.log('in response')
  console.log(response[0].headers)
  return response[0].statusCode
 
  
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log("there was an error")
  console.error(error)
  return 'test'+error
  
})
 
  //return response;
}

export { sendMailToMe };
```

This is imported and called as follows to pages/api/sendMail.js

```
import { sendMailToMe } from "../../utils/sendMailToMe";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
      const { email, fullName, message,test } = req.body;
      if (
        typeof (email || fullName || test || message) === "undefined"
      ) {
        console.log(" ************* Invalid Data received ************ ");

        return res
          .status(400)
          .send({ error: "bad request, missing required data!" });
      } else {
        //  Data received as expected
       console.log('Calling sendMailToMe')
         const sendGridResult =  await sendMailToMe(
            fullName,
            message,
            email
          )
          .then((response)=>{console.log(response)}) //res.status(200).send({test: 'test'})})
          .catch((err) =>{ console.log(err)})//res.status(400).send({error:"Error in Sendgrid", errMsg:err})})
// API returns here regardless of outcome 
           res.status(200).send({test: 'returning here on error or success'})

      }
    }else{
        res.status(400).send({ error: "Must use POST method" });
    }
        
      

  //res.status(400).send({ error: "bad request somehow" });
  
}
```

I am trying to get the result of mail.send() back to the api so I can return the proper response. Right now sendMail.js returns 200 even if mail.send() fails. The console logs the response or error in sendMailToMe() but I can't get the response or error back to sendmail.js. Any pointers in the right direction appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not on promises in next or react but the use of this particular utility - @sendgrid/mail and whether it is suitable for a react application. Which is better answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56109870/how-to-send-email-with-reactjs-and-sendgrid

Comment: @SteveTomlin Thank you for the resource. I am really more trying to understand the return part of an async function. The sendgrid library works fine so my question is more about trying to wrap my head around why I cannot 'return' the response. I was certain it is more a lack of understanding of the async/await process then the sendgrid utility. I am assuming I would have the same issue whether using @sendgrid/mail or any other utility. Do you think my issue is utility specific? I will experiment using a simple fetch() in replacement of sendgrid. I'm new here so appreciate the guidance.